Unable to order based on joined table with Many to Many relationship
I'm trying to order a set of paged results based on the existence of many to many relationship. I can write a query by hand that does this, but I'm trying to figure out how to do this the sequelize way.
My Code:
const include = [];
const page = 1;
const rowsPerPage = 30;
const sortByTagId = 1134;

include.push(...[
  { association: User.Tags }
]);

await User.findAll({
  include,
  order: [
    fn('BOOL_OR', where(col('usertags.tagId'), sortByTagId)),
    'ASC',
  ],
  group: ['UserModel.id'],
  offset: rowsPerPage * (page - 1),
  limit: rowsPerPage,
});

Sequelize then produces the following query:
SELECT 
  "UserModel".*, 
  "usertags"."id" AS "_0",
  "usertags"."uuid" AS "_1",
  "usertags"."createdAt" AS "_2",
  "usertags"."deletedAt" AS "_3",
  "usertags"."updatedAt" AS "_4",
  "usertags"."tagId" AS "_6",
  "usertags"."userId" AS "_8"
FROM (
  SELECT 
    "UserModel"."id",
    "UserModel"."uuid",
    "UserModel"."createdAt",
    "UserModel"."deletedAt",
    "UserModel"."updatedAt",
    "UserModel"."status",
    "UserModel"."locationId",
    "UserModel"."firstName",
    "UserModel"."lastName",
    "UserModel"."suffix",
    "UserModel"."email", 
    "UserModel"."phone"
  FROM "users" AS "UserModel"
  WHERE ("UserModel"."deletedAt" IS NULL) 
    AND ( 
      SELECT "userId" 
      FROM "usertags" AS "usertags" 
      WHERE (
        "usertags"."deletedAt" IS NULL 
        AND "usertags"."userId" = "UserModel"."id"
      ) 
      LIMIT 1 
    ) IS NOT NULL 
  GROUP BY "UserModel"."id" 
  ORDER BY bool_or("usertags"."tagId" = 1134) ASC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
) AS "UserModel" 
  INNER JOIN "usertags" AS "usertags" ON "UserModel"."id" = "usertags"."userId" AND "usertags"."deletedAt" IS NULL 
ORDER BY bool_or("usertags"."tagId" = 1134) ASC;

This query is invalid and produces the following error:
missing FROM-clause entry for table "usertags"
I suspect sequelize is omitting my association because it doesn't see any references to it but is ignoring my call to literal() I suspect that I might be able to solve this problem by getting rid of literal() but I haven't been able to figure out how to do so while still specifying a value for tagId.
I've tried experimenting with raw: true but this doesn't help in any way.
FYI: The code above is an approximation of something more complex from a proprietary codebase, I've modified it to make it easier to read and not proprietary. I apologize for any mistakes I might have made and will try to edit accordingly if necessary.
Edit: I'm targeting a query like this (tested directly against a database):
SELECT
--   string_agg(CAST("usertags"."userTagId" as varchar(255)), ','),
      "UserModel".*
FROM "Users" AS "UserModel" 
    INNER JOIN "userTags" on "usertags"."userId" = "UserModel"."id"
WHERE ("UserModel"."deletedAt" IS NULL) 
GROUP BY "UserModel"."id"
ORDER BY bool_or("usertags"."tagId" = 1134) DESC 
LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0;

This will return all users ordered by if they have a particular tag. The comment is included for diagnostic purposes.

That bool_or() makes no sense to me; what is that supposed to do in an ORDER BY clause?

@Pointy I've edited the question to include an example query that hopefully better explains what I am trying to do.

I suspect this is a bug in sequelize. I've filed a bug report here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/17587

You want to sort those users first that have tag no 1234, then those that don't... is that correct?

@SalmanArshad Yep thats the goal, The query I have does that but I need to do it in sequelize. I'm open to other approaches so long as they are pure sequelize.

@SalmanArshad I was going to award the bounty to your answer, but you deleted it...

@acol bounty was awarded before deletion. Someone downvoted my answer (and upvoted the other). That might explain the confusion.

Your query does not define what UserModel is. Sequelize generates a subquery for UserModel, as it is unaware of that being an alias according to your intention. So you will need to specify the alias:
const include = [];
const page = 1;
const rowsPerPage = 30;
const sortByTagId = 1134;

include.push(...[
  { association: User.Tags, required: true }
]);

await User.findAll({
  attributes: [
      'users', 'UserModel'
  ],
  include,
  order: [
    fn('BOOL_OR', where(col('usertags.tagId'), sortByTagId)),
    'ASC',
  ],
  group: ['UserModel.id'],
  offset: rowsPerPage * (page - 1),
  limit: rowsPerPage,
});


This didn't help, I meant to award the bounty to the other answer but did this one by mistake as the other answer had been deleted...
